# Where to upload Expansion File on market?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have created expansion file with "main.1.packagename.obb" name after searching on the internet.
But I can not find any option on developer account to upload that file.

If anyone can show me screenshot of market that where to upload that file or how to thats appreciated.

I can only find this in my account. Can you please send me any link or screenshot where it actually shows how to upload.

[image]

Here is the screen which shows after upload, where is the link to upload expansion file??

[image]

Comment: you can upload that extension file while You are uploading Your apk. There is a question at the bottom of that upload dialog....

Comment: hi, i have edited my question with image. I dont find   any uploading thing for expansion file. only apk file upload avaiable.

Comment: just go on and load your apk, after that You will see it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
In new developer console, there is no option to upload apk in first time.
But first upload dummy apk and than upload new apk will enable option to add expansion file.
So its a problem due to new dev console.

Here is the screenshot while adding 2nd apk and than expansion file

[image]